Changing font of first column in table using pgfplotstabletypeset
Using pgfplotstabletypeset, I would like to specify that every entry in the first column be typeset using \bfseries\sffamily\small, but I'm not sure how to do so. I attach a MWE.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  col sep=&,row sep=\\,
  string type,
  every head row/.style={before row=\toprule},
  every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
]{
  Angle & 0 & 90 & 180 & -90 \\ 
  Count & 20 & 28 & 21 & 19 \\
}
\end{document}

The current output is as follows:


The following style for a column allows to modify the content where ##1 represents the actual data
postproc cell content/.style={@cell content={\small\textbf{##1}}}

However, you need to reference the column first to apply its style. Currently your first row is assumed to be a header. You can disable this behavior by setting header=false, but then a first row becomes 0 1 2 3 4. You can hide the header with every head row/.style={output empty row}.
All together it results in
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  col sep=&,row sep=\\,
  string type,
  every head row/.style={output empty row, before row=\toprule},
  every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
  header=false,
  columns/0/.style={
    postproc cell content/.style={@cell content={\small\textbf{##1}}}
  }
]{
  Angle & 0 & 90 & 180 & -90 \\ 
  Count & 20 & 28 & 21 & 19 \\
}
\end{document}



Thank you for this clear answer, especially the part about disabling the header. I think this is the key that was missing from my various attempts to attack this problem.
